# UIScrollView behaves unexpectedly when scrolling inside UIPickerView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uipickerview

I have two textfiled in my view. An UIPickerView or normal keyboard(depending on which type of textfiled) is shown from bottom when a textfield is pressed. A UIScrollView wrappers everything in my view.
The ViewController.h file looks like this:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController<UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textNormal;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textScroll;
@property UIPickerView * picker;

@end
```

I mixed some code to do some scrolling to the scrollview in order to make textfield visible when a keyboard or a pickerview is shown.

The ViewController.m file:

```
@interface MyViewController ()

@property BOOL keyboardVisable;
@property CGPoint offset;
@property CGRect frame;
@property UIPickerView * picker;
@end

@implementation MyViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.keyboardVisable = NO;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidHide:) name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hideKeyboard)];
    tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    [self.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

    self.picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
    self.textScroll.inputView = self.picker;
    self.picker.delegate = self;
    self.picker.dataSource = self;
    self.picker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;

}
-(void)hideKeyboard
{
    NSLog(@"hide now");
    [self.scrollView endEditing:YES];
}


- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)notif{
    if(self.keyboardVisable)
        return;

    NSLog(@"keyboard did show");

    NSDictionary* info = [notif userInfo];
    NSValue* aValue = [info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey];
    CGSize keyboardSize = [aValue CGRectValue].size;

    // Save the current location so we can restore
    // when keyboard is dismissed
    self.offset = self.scrollView.contentOffset;
    self.frame = self.scrollView.frame;

    // Resize the scroll view to make room for the keyboard
    CGRect viewFrame = self.scrollView.frame;
    viewFrame.size.height -= keyboardSize.height;
    self.scrollView.frame = viewFrame;

    CGRect textFieldRect = [self.textScroll frame];
    textFieldRect.origin.y += 10;

    [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:textFieldRect animated:YES];

    // Keyboard is now visible
    self.keyboardVisable = YES;

}


- (void)keyboardDidHide:(NSNotification *)notif{
    if(!self.keyboardVisable)
        return;

    NSLog(@"keyboard did hide");


    //self.scrollView.contentOffset = self.offset;
    self.scrollView.frame = self.frame;
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:self.offset animated:YES];

    self.keyboardVisable = NO;

}
```

These codes work normally when a normal textfield is pressed.
(The scrollview would change it's frame size and offset in order to make textfield viewable, and it will be back to normal when anywhere but the keyboard is pressed)

However, they don't work on textfield with inputView == pickerview.
The scrollview would change it's frame size as expected. Once the pickerview is scrolled by an user, the background(scrollview) will suddenly scroll to top and become unscrollable unexpectedly.

Thanks!

Comment: When you tap on the textfield where the picker would normally pop up, do you make the texfield resignfromfirstresponder? This would normally pop up the keyboard and thus making the scrollview move up. Do you have the same for when the pickerview is showing too? I was wondering if you have it moved twice.

Comment: You mean if I called resignfromfirstresponder, iOS will help me to resize the scrollview?

Comment: possibly, the textfield will try to fire up the keyboard and your code will fire to change the scrollview. I assume your picker also tries to do the same?